# Exercism Bash Track

Tags: bash, bats-core

I am trying out the bash course at exercism.io
https://exercism.io/my/solutions/8d68ead0c1ad4caabf25410806ade766

I have installed the exercise files, installed bats, and when i run the the test: bats hello_world_test.sh

It outputs and error:

```
$ bats hello_world_test.sh
 ✗ Say Hi!
   (in test file hello_world_test.sh, line 6)
     `[ "$status" -eq 0 ]' failed
```

The code for the bats hello_world_test.sh is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

@test "Say Hi!" {
  run bash hello_world.sh

  [ "$status" -eq 0 ]
  [ "$output" = "Hello, World!" ]
}
```

Comment: Nice, good for you! What is the question?

Comment: What is bats? What is in hello_world_test.sh? Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @glennjackman Bats is a Bash testing framework that's actually pretty neat: https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core (Or maybe you knew that and were just pointing out that the question should be more self-contained.)

Comment: Your link to exercism.io doesn't work unless we are signed in. Which I doubt anyone is going to bother with. Please share the code in your `hello_world_test.sh` script so we can help out more. Otherwise we are blind.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of structure to my question! I'm fairly new to posting questions on here.

Comment: Backticks are for code segments shorter than one line -- use four-space indents, as created by the `{}` button in the editor, when adding longer snippets; this formats them appropriately and enables syntax highlighting.

Comment: Note that this still isn't complete enough to test, since it has as unincluded dependency in `hello_world.sh`.

Comment: (Also, I'm a little skeptical of any teaching resource advising using `.sh` extensions for bash scripts; it's a common practice, but not a good one -- scripts with a shebang and an execute bit are executables, and executables on UNIX don't have extensions: You run `ls`, not `ls.elf`; and when you run `python setup.py install` to install a Python module, the entry-point scripts it creates don't end in `.py`, only the modules/libraries do).

Answer (score 0):

This line tells us everything we need to know about this:

```
run bash hello_world.sh
```

... your `hello_world_test.sh` script is trying to execute a script named `hello_world.sh`. The `[ "$status" -eq 0 ]` line is failing because bash returned an *error code* (most likely because the `hello_world.sh` script does not exist). You will need to create this file.

Simply creating the script is not enough to make the test case pass though; it's also expecting the output "Hello, World!" from this script. I'm not going to tell you how to do this because that would defeat the purpose, but I will refer you to a [HOW TO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html) that should get you up and running. I would encourage you to go through the [whole guide](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html), there's lots of good info in there for someone just getting started. It may take you a few tries, but you'll get it :-)